# PHP replace text with image

Tags: php, string, replace

This would be an Array of data:

```
$array = array("sad","bow","blabla");
```

IF
`$input = "I love Stackoverflow! :bow: so much";`

Output should be:

```
I love Stackoverflow <img src="smiley/bow.gif" alt=""/> so much
```

**What would be the best and fastest way to accomplish this ?**

Comment: I'm PHP newbie, so I don't know where to start... any help is appreciated

Comment: or [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: why would you use the array? and not just replace the ":[a-z]+:" pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(':('=>"sad",'-_-'=>"bow",'bla'=>"blabla");
$input = "I love Stackoverflow! :bow: so much";
$output = str_replace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $input);
```

**Edit:** Sorry..didn't read it clearly.

Attempt 2:

```
preg_replace('`:(\w+):`', '<img src="smily/\1.gif" alt=""/>', $input);
```

Someting like that anyway.

Might have to use `$1` in place of `\1`. Read [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
//string replace example.
$input = "I love Stackoverflow! :bow: so much"; 
echo str_replace(":bow:","< img src='smiley/bow.gif' alt=''/>",$input)."<br /><br />";


//use string replace with foreach 
$array = array("sad","bow","blabla");

foreach($array as $value)
{
  $input = "I love Stackoverflow! :'".$value."': so much";
  echo str_replace(":'".$value."':","< img src='smiley/$value.gif' alt=''/>",$input);  
}
```